# Twilio: Sending SMS to US numbers is not working

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

When we are using Twilio SMS programmable interface to send a SMS to a USA number, it is not working. However, if we use the same account and try to send a SMS to an Indian number, the SMS is getting successfully delivered.

Is there are any specific setting to make twilio work successfully for sending a SMS to a USA number?

Thanks

Ahir

Answer (score 0):

Update the SMS geographic permissions - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181108-How-International-SMS-Permissions-work

Comment: I've upgraded my permissions, still doesn't work